# Error when swapping an alias to a function in cygwin bash

Tags: bash, cygwin

**Problem:**
When recreating an alias as a function in my .bashrc file an error occurs when the name of the function is the same as the previous name of the alias.

**Details:**

- I have removed the prior alias altogether from my .bashrc file
- When changing the name of the function to something that wasn't previously used it works correctly
- The code higher up in the file seems to work without errors as well
- [Edit] **I can also run old aliases that no longer exist in my .bashrc file**

**Example:**

When changing this:

```
alias npp='(/c/SolsApplications/NotePad++/notepad++.exe &> /dev/null &)'
```

To this:

```
npp()
{
    if [[ $1 != null ]]; then
        ('/c/SolsApplications/NotePad++/notepad++.exe' $1 &> /dev/null &)
    else
        ('/c/SolsApplications/NotePad++/notepad++.exe' &> /dev/null &);
    fi
}
```

The following error occurs when refreshing the .bashrc file:

```
bash: /c/Users/Owner/.bashrc: line 33: syntax error near unexpected token `('

bash: /c/Users/Owner/.bashrc: line 33: `npp()'
```

**What I have tried:**

- Clearing my .bash_history file
- Restarting bash
- Searching the internet
- Adding a space like so: "npp ()"

Comment: Feel free to suggest edits or request specifications. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have `npp()` already defined. Therefore when sourcing `.bashrc` it thinks you are trying to execute `npp()` which is syntactically wrong. You need to undefine `npp()`. To remove previous definition of `npp()` use `unset npp`.

Comment: @alvits I executed the command unset npp in the command line for bash or whatever it's called. The error still persists. Is that what you meant me to do?

Comment: @John1024 I'm not ruling that out as a possibility. I just find it odd that when I change the function npp to be named say, npppp, it seems to work.

Comment: If the issue is syntax, it will fail no matter what new name is used. But the mere fact that it works once whenever new name is introduced, it means the old name is intact. And to verify that the old name exists, just run the old name and you should see `notepad++` comes up. As to why the `cygwin` is keeping the old names regardless of unsetting them, that's probably what your question should be

Comment: @John1024 just made a copy of the file in a repo https://github.com/solomonbroadbent/test.git

Comment: For what its worth, your file runs without error for me under bash on linux.  @Alvits my bash (linux not cygwin) does not produce the error that the OP sees even if `npp` is previously defined.

Comment: @John1024 - that's the expected behavior. But it seems OP is using `cygwin` or similar product that store function definition in windows' registry.

Comment: @alvits, that would be `unalias npp`, rather.

Comment: Anyhow, the easy way to settle this question is to run `alias >&2` from the `.bashrc` immediately prior to the definition at hand, and see if any definition is given in output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - `alias npp` wasn't in the previous version of the post. Now that it's there, that would be the way to get rid of it.

Comment: @alvits, ...so, good catch -- that was a cygwin extension I wasn't aware of. Write up an answer?

Comment: @alvits my .bashrc no longer contains that alias, only the function.

Comment: @Squighopper25, ...the point alvits made is that on cygwin, removing it from your `.bashrc` may not be sufficient. To test this, run `alias` with no arguments, and see if the alias is listed as still present.

Comment: ...cygwin *does* have some annoyingly invasive patches to the shell, so while I wasn't aware of this one, after seeing other bugs they introduced I'm not exactly surprised either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I believe my latest edit proves your above suggestion that the alias is still present. (Even when the alias is removed from .bashrc it still functions)

Comment: Would any body happen to know where else the aliases and such may be stored so I can manually delete them

Comment: @Squighopper25, ...well, alvits already suggested earlier in this that cygwin may be putting them in the registry, though I can't personally speak to the truth of this. Have you tried using `unalias` and seeing if that persists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases are simple prefix expansion. Thus, if you already have an alias `npp` provided, your function definition can be changed by it to the following:

```
(/c/SolsApplications/NotePad++/notepad++.exe &> /dev/null &)() {
    if [[ $1 != null ]]; then
        ('/c/SolsApplications/NotePad++/notepad++.exe' $1 &> /dev/null &)
    else
        ('/c/SolsApplications/NotePad++/notepad++.exe' &> /dev/null &);
    fi
}
```

Finding the place this alias is added and removing it should suffice. If you have trouble doing so, simply unalias it immediately before defining the function:

```
unalias npp
npp() {
  ...
}
```

Consider also starting your interactive shell with logging, and reviewing those logs, to figure out where your alias is generated (should it be coming from a dotfile or similar):

```
# This will start a new login shell, logging each command run to stderr
# ...with source file and line number for content from scripts.
PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l
```

Comment: I believe you have solved the issue to some extent. I think "unalias" needs to be redone every login. However, that isn't an issue really, for the time being I can use another alias to unstage the deprecated ones 'till I learn more about the path logging stuff you were talking about.
 
As a side note, windows 10's anniversary update will natively include the bash shell, so I am told. This means issues like this with third-party software won't bug people like me forever

Comment: My understanding is that this "native" shell will actually be running in a VM, so if you want it to act as if it's on the same host as the rest of your Windows software, not so much.

Comment: ...also, Microsoft doesn't exactly have a great track record on this count. See https://web.archive.org/web/20150310123118/http://gopher.quux.org:70/Humor%20and%20Fun/Microsoft_KSH.txt%7C/MBOX-MESSAGE/1 for a bit of history on one of their earlier attempts to include a "real" UNIX shell.

Comment: @Squighopper25, ...btw, to use what I gave you easily, consider running the following at your command line: `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l 2>&1 | grep -e alias`

Comment: Literally my one wish for windows 10 was native bash... Ill give that command a try. Cheers